# In Flash Builder + Java how to check if a number of Session ID is valid or not?

Tags: java, apache-flex, servlets, flex4, flash-builder

I'm using Flash Builder 4 + Java + BlazeDS

I have the session ID number of each user and would like to check if this session ID is still valid, if valid return true if I do not return false.

I could not find a method in the API to do that.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/javadoc/flex/messaging/FlexContext.html

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to check the sessionID in Flex or in Java?  Is this an ID you create; or a web page cookie that is used to track server side sessions?  Or something created on Java to track sessions?

Comment: Yes it is in Java that would validate the session ID.

Sorry forgot to mension, I'm using BlazeDS.

I get the number of the session ID when the user enters the site, and registration in the database

An example of how to do it;
http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=lcconnections_3.html

Comment: So, if I understand.  On the server side, you want to be able to determine whether the sessionID is valid or not?  One approach is to set a variable when the session is created; and check for it's existence on later calls.

Comment: there is a way to send the session ID to a method and return if it is valid or not?

Comment: What I really want is only whether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: The way sessionIDs work in every web application I have worked on is: A server side session has some form of SessionID; and that is set as a cookie in the browser upon the first request. The cookie is sent with every future request; whether a service call from Flex or an HTML Page load. The application server uses the cookie value to sync the request with a server side session. This has nothing to do w/ your own application's :ogin. A user can have a valid session w/o logging in. I recommend setting a "isLoggedIn" session variable after the user authenticates. Check it to validate each request

Comment: Now I understand, you're right! So ... I want to prevent the user to do a login in two places at once, the way you taught me, how will I know if the user closed the browser in your house to allow it to open in the company?  
Thank you very much Reboog711

Comment: It is rarely worth the cost of implementation to prevent the user from logging in at two places at once.  You won't be able to use sessions; because each browser will have a different session.  Basically, when the user authenticates successfully; store a flag in some permanent data store--such as a database.  When the session expires; clear the flag.